# GCP Vertex.ai custom container endpoint hosting giving format error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

After spending multiple hours, I created this sample model endpoint code I want to host on vertex.ai, these are the three files I have

**1. Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7
USER root
ADD . /home/model-server/
WORKDIR /home/model-server/
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt
CMD exec gunicorn -b :5000 --max-requests 1 --graceful-timeout 300 -t 600 main:app
```

2. Main.py -- contains flask app

```
import json
from flask import Flask, request, Response, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['JSON_SORT_KEYS'] = False

@app.route('/health', methods=['GET'])
def health_check():
   return Response(response=json.dumps({"status": 'healthy'}), status=200, mimetype="application/json")

@app.route('/vertex_predict/', methods=['POST'])
def main():
   request_json = request.get_json()
   request_instances = request_json['instances']

   output = {'predictions':
               [
                   {
                       'result' : "this is working with static output"
                   }
               ]
           }
   return jsonify(output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

3. Requirement.txt

```
pandas==1.1.1
numpy==1.21.5
flask==2.2.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
```

this is pretty simple code which we are able to put in artifact registry then

1. Import this as model in vertex.ai Model registry
2. Then trying to deloy it as endpoint

I tried multiple times but after almost 20 mins, it fails and showing this error all the time

```
jsonPayload: {
levelname: "ERROR"
logtag: "F"
message: "exec /bin/sh: exec format error"
}
```

the same flask app is working fine on local machine, not sure what is wrong here on vertex.ai. Can someone please help me here or guide the next steps